# nohup cmd & in i3

Tags: nohup, i3

When I run `nohup google-chrome &` in i3 terminal it will start a new terminal with google-chrome.
But if I close the terminal where I ran the `nohup` command then the google-chrome terminal will also close.

How can I start the google-chrome independently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `google-chrome &!` to detach it from controlling shell, so exiting the shell won't kill leftover jobs. Alternatively, use `disown` shell builtin to detach the job. Note that it will work in `zsh` and `bash` shells, not all of them (but `dash` for example won't kill remaining backgrounded jobs in the first place)

More portable (if awkward) way may be `sh -c "google-chrome &" &`. That would start a subshell in background, which would start google-chrome in background and terminate - thus leaving no dangling jobs in original shell to kill.

Comment: I think that's a `zsh`ism, but seemingly works for the questioner, it may not work in all shells though

Comment: @EricRenouf while it will work in most situations, your comment is correct, so answer updated. Thanks.